# Parent construct laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller

I want use parent construct for calling once variable

```
class Home extends Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        $expiresAt = 10;
    }

    public function index() {

        $data = Cache::remember('table', $expiresAt, function() {
                return DB::table('table')
                        ->ORDERBY('date', 'DESC')
                        ->WHERE('status', 1)
                        ->paginate(8);
        });

        return view('frontend.pages.home', compact('title', 'meta', 'description', 'all_resto'));
    }
}
```

I have this response **"Undefined variable: expiresAt"**
Where is the problem

Comment: `$this->expiresAt`.... it needs to be a class property, not a local variable, if you're sharing it between methods

Answer (score 0):

```
class Home extends Controller {
    public $expiresAt;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->expiresAt = 10; // change over here.
    }

    public function index() {

        $data = Cache::remember('table', $expiresAt, function() {
                return DB::table('table')
                        ->ORDERBY('date', 'DESC')
                        ->WHERE('status', 1)
                        ->paginate(8);
        });

        return view('frontend.pages.home', compact('title', 'meta', 'description', 'all_resto'));
    }
}
```

*Sidenote*: In the classes you are extending `Home` class, you can use `$expiresAt` variable by using

`$this->expiresAt`